# CSS/HTML Dropdown

Tags: html, css

I'm not really good at coding html or css, so I need some help.

[image]

In short, when you hover over the triangle, it will display the dropdown menu with the list of options (user control panel, private messsages, etc). What's the best way to achieve this using html, css, etc? If you could provide the code, I'd much appreciate it.

Cheers, Spencer

Comment: Take a look at Stu Nicholls CSSPlay Demos - http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/ - I'm sure you will find one that serves your needs

Comment: If you tried to work it out yourself, and then asked specifically why something wasn't working, you'd probably learn how to do it more effectively. `:)`

Comment: You want us to write out this code for you?  That's not what SO is all about.

Comment: I should I worded my question differently. I didn't want the whole code, but more of how I would do it. Sorry.

Comment: It's not about wording.  Typically one asks questions after a serious programming attempt was made.  In other words, demonstrate some effort before asking others to put forth effort.

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide you with all the code, but here's what I think to be a good help.

```
<div>
  Welcome back dude!
  <div id="triangle">
    <div id="menu">
       <!-- Here goes the menu links whatever -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please notice that the menu div is contained in the triangle div.

Then in your CSS code, write something like this:

```
#menu { display:none; position:absolute; }
#triangle { position:relative; }
#triangle:hover #menu { display:block; } /* This is what makes the menu show up. When you hover triangle (or anything in it, like menu) then the menu is visible */
```

The position attributes will be for the #menu not to alter other elements in the page when it shows.

Then you'll have to make adjustments to the triangle menu, if needed.

Comment: Wonderful! Is it possible so when you hover over the triangle, the menu is still displayed so you can click links on it without it disappearing?

Comment: @Spencer, what do you mean? Did you get the CSS menu to work properly?